# CoefficientList with multivariable

Tags: polynomials

Consider:

```
t = (1 + x)^3 (1 - y - x)^2
Expand[t]
```

Now:

```
CoefficientList[t, {x, y}]
```

The output is:

{{1, -2, 1}, {1, -4, 3}, {-2, 0, 3}, {-2, 4, 1}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}

Now I don't understand this output. Can someone please explain how it relates to the expanded value of t above? Also, as a second equation, can someone show how to use this matrix to reproduce t?

Comment: Hint: each row corresponds to `1`, `x`, `x^2`,..., `x^5` and each column corresponds to `1`, `y`, `y^2`; and the entries corresponds to their products.

Comment: What you ask in the second question is shown in the documentation for `CoefficientList` under "Properties & Relations."

Answer (score 6):

This is in the docs, of course.

`{1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}.{{1, -2, 1}, {1, -4, 3}, {-2, 0, 3}, {-2, 4, 1}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}.{1, y, y^2}` is your polynomial.

More generally, the matrix output of `CoefficientList[poly, {var1, var2}]` is such that

```
{1, var1, …, var1^n}.CoefficientList[poly, {var1, var2}].{1, var2, …, var2^m} == poly
```

where the powers `n, m` respectively are the highest powers to which `var1, var2` appear in `poly`.

Comment: It is in the docs, but I've always found the documentation for this particular function somewhat opaque. Your reconstruction of the polynomial makes it totally clear what's going on (+1), to the point where it'd be nice if that was somewhere in the documentation (maybe it is and I missed it?).

Comment: An example appears under "Basic Examples" of "Matrix of coefficients for a quadratic form: `CoefficientList[1 + a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, {x, y}]`" - I didn't know for certain what `CoefficientList` did, but that summary line alone made me about 90% sure that my guess would be correct. I didn't even need to look at the output of that line in the docs to formulate my model. I presumed other people would do the same :P

Comment: This is one of the worst documented functions in mathematica

Answer (score 4):

```
t = (1 + x)^3 (1 - y - x)^2;

cl = CoefficientList[t, {x, y}];

(pwrs = Array[x^(#1 - 1) y^(#2 - 1) &, Dimensions[cl]])//MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
t == Total[cl*pwrs, 2] // Simplify
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

This won't really fit in a comment, but I wanted to briefly expand on `Patrick Stevens`' and `Bob Hanlon`'s answers. If they would like to incorporate this answer into theirs, I will delete this answer.

In order to generalize the clever observation that

```
{1, var1, …, var1^n}.CoefficientList[poly, {var1, var2}].{1, var2, …, var2^m}
```

is the polynomial in question when there are *two* variables, there is a variant in which `Dot` works to reconstruct the polynomial in an arbitrary number of variables.

By way of example, take

```
poly = x + y^2 + z^3;
vars = {x, y, z};
cl = CoefficientList[poly, vars];
degrees = Exponent[poly, vars];
```

We can reconstruct the polynomial from the `CoefficientList` `cl` and the list of polynomial degrees `degrees` with

```
Dot[cl, Sequence @@ Reverse @ MapThread[PowerRange[1, #1^#2, #1] &, {vars, powers}]]
```

To pick this apart, note that

```
Reverse @ MapThread[PowerRange[1, #1^#2, #1] &, {vars, powers}]
```

merely automates creating the lists of monomials:

```
(* {{1, z, z^2, z^3}, {1, y, y^2}, {1, x}} *)
```

We have to reverse the list because the ordering of the tensors in `Dot` matters. Then, `Dot` does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html):

```
Fold[
 FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &,
 CoefficientList[t, {x, y}],
 {x, y}]
% - t // Simplify
(*
  1 + x + (-2 - 2 x) x^2 + 
   x^4 (1 + x) + (-2 - 4 x + 4 x^3 + 2 x^4) y + (1 + 3 x + x^2 (3 + x)) y^2

  0
*)
```

---

Another alternative:

```
CoefficientList[t, {x, y}].y^Range[0, Exponent[t, y]].x^Range[0, Exponent[t, x]]
```